# In Python, how do I check that the user has entered a name instead of a number?

Tags: python-2.7

In Python, how do I check that the user has entered a name instead of a number, when asking for user input as string? I want a string input in the form of their name, but I want to use error checking to make sure the user doesn't enter a number.

Comment: Are names allowed to have numbers in them?

Comment: No, numbers should not be allowed. Only a persons name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function that determines if there are any non-alphabetic characters in the input string:

```
def is_valid_name(s):
    return all(char.isalpha() for char in s)
```

This will return `True` if **only** alphabetic characters exist in the string, `False` otherwise.

```
>>> print(is_valid_name("Hello123"))
False
>>> print(is_valid_name("Hello"))
True
```

Note that this doesn't work with spaces:

```
>>> print(is_valid_name("Hello World"))
False
```

So it can be adjusted if necessary:

```
def is_valid_name(s):
    return all(char.isalpha() or char.isspace() for char in s)
```

See here:

```
>>> print(is_valid_name("Hello World"))
True
```

Comment: The `is_valid_name()` definition provided gives the same result as `s.isalpha()`, except for empty strings.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It's a little different now. Needed to do some testing :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the exact requirements for being a name and not a number, you can probably just call `.isalpha()` on the string you get from the user.

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) for assorted methods to check whether a string satisfies certain criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna check correct in english dictionary then you can use pyenchant ... use pip to install it ... its east to use and gives true if spelling of a word is correct and false if word doesn't exist in english dictionary.

pip install pyenchant